# Using dollar sign for looping through multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dollar-sign

I have one big data frame df.
I used `split()` to devide it into smaller data frames. thes can be viewed by:  `view(a$`1`)` , `view(a$`2`)`,...

I wondered if i could use a loop for this to view all the smaller data frames:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  b <- paste0("a$", `i`)
  print(b)
  View(b)
  i= i+1
}
```

However the paste0 function returns as$1, to acces the dataframe I need as$'1'. Anyone any idea how to do this? Tried searching for it but found nothing.

Comment: use `a[[i]]`instead

Comment: thanks this solved it! For anyone interested use: b <- a[[`i`]]